# Compiler error on member initialization of c-style array member (compared with std::array member)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, member-initialization

I encountered this problem while initializing a member array variable (c-style). Interestingly converting the member into a `std::array<>` solves the problem.
See below:

```
struct A {
  A(int aa) : a(aa) {}

  A(const A &a) = delete;
  A &operator=(const A &a) = delete;

private:
  int a;
  std::vector<int> v;
};

struct B1 {
  B1() : a1{{{1}, {2}}} {} // -> compiles OK (gcc 9.2)

private:
  std::array<A, 2> a1;
};

struct B2 {
  B2()
    : a2{{1}, {2}} // -> error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)' (gcc 9.2)
  {} 

private:
  A a2[2];
};
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f4nd4fr4x)

My question is why is this difference in (compiler) behavior? I was assuming that functionality-wise they are pretty much the same (I understand `std::array<>` is more of an aggregate instead of a pure container, like vector - I might be wrong though).

Additional observation:

- The compiler allows c-style array if I remove the `vector<>` member in `A`
- GCC 9.5 does not raise any issues. Does it mean it's a GCC bug (I couldn't find anything on the release notes)?

**Update:**
It is a GCC bug:
[Brace initialization of array sometimes fails if no copy constructor (reported in 4.9 and resolved in 9.4)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707)

Comment: Change the compiler version you're using. The program works starting from gcc 9.4. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sYrb1cEj8)

Comment: @JasonLiam I noticed that the program works in GCC > 9.5 and onwards. Does that mean it was a GCC bug or improvement? I could not find any official explanation for this (bug report and/or release notes).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a gcc bug which has been submitted as: [GCC rejects valid program involving initialization of array in member initializer list](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106788)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean it's a GCC bug

Yes, this seems to be a gcc bug that has been fixed in gcc 9.4. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sYrb1cEj8).

A bug for the same has been submitted as:

[GCC rejects valid program involving initialization of array in member initializer list](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106788)